# What is a good book on electricity?

Tags: electromagnetism

What is a good book on electricity such as generators for someone who is a beginner and want to learn about the generator and such.

Comment: I see thanks for the reccomendation. Are there any good books for someone who also want to learn telecommunication

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at: 
Power Generation, Operation and Control  by Allen Wood

Answer (score 0):

I found the following book for free at my dump [Teach Yourself Electricity by C. W. Wilman (1942 originally published)](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=teach%20yourself%20electricity%201960&sprefix=Teach%20yourself%20el,stripbooks,319). It's a really solid and short introduction. The link is a search on Amazon which you kind find low cost version of it.